# DependencyProperty of type Style in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, dependency-properties

In a custom control I'd like to use a Style (given as DependencyProperty) for a TextBlock in my Template.

MyControl.cs

```
public static DependencyProperty HeadingStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HeadingStyle",
                                typeof (Style),
                                typeof (MyControlElement),
                                new PropertyMetadata(new Style(typeof(TextBlock))));

public Style HeadingStyle {
    get { return (Style) GetValue(HeadingStyleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeadingStyleProperty, value); }
}
```

MyControl.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Getting error on BasedOn="TemplateBinding -->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{TemplateBinding HeadingStyle}" x:Key="Heading" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Heading}" Text="StyledHeading" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I get compiler error 'HeadingStyle' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

Do I have to modify the DataType of my DP from Style to a more specific one? Or what causes this error. The initial value of DP is set to Style for TargetType TextBlock...

Comment: It's WPF, you may need to change TargetType to include type, `TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"`

Comment: this doesn't fix my problem. I think it is caused in my DP (maybe I have to define the DP in another way if it is a Style...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `Style` **does not** derive from `DependencyObject`, so you cannot set any binding on it.

If you want your `TextBlock` (which is part of the template) to be styled by your property, simply set the `TemplateBinding` on its `Style` property directly (what would be the purpose of the style you defined as a resource anyway?). This can be done in two ways. One is to use fully qualified property name:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <TextBlock Style="{TemplateBinding local:MyControl.HeadingStyle}" (...) />
</ControlTemplate>
```

The other way, more commonly used, is to use simplified property name, but it requires the `ControlTemplate.TargetType` to be specified:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <TextBlock Style="{TemplateBinding HeadingStyle}" (...) />
</ControlTemplate>
```

The second method works because the XAML parser is smart enough to know how to resolve the `HeadingStyle` property - if you didn't specify `ControlTemplate.TargetType`, you'd get the exact same error you're getting right now.

You could of course trick the compiler to compile your code by using fully qualified property name:

```
<Style x:Key="Heading" BasedOn="{TemplateBinding local:MyControl.HeadingStyle}" (...) />
```

but that would result in a runtime error saying that `TemplateBindingExpression` cannot be converted to `Style`.

Comment: thanks that is working! Using the style in my ControlTemplate as Resource can be left in my case, so I bind the HeadingStyle directly.